# List item storage in SQL

Tags: 2013, sql-server, xml, list-item

So I'm having some performance issues with some large queries against SharePoint (yes, I'm already using CAML), so I decided to take a peek at the SharePoint database despite the dire warnings never to do so. I expected list item data to be stored in columns like Datetime1, Datetime2, etc, but instead discovered (to my horror), that list column data seems to be stored in *XML* in the `AllUserData.tp_ColumnSet` column.

```
<datetime2>2010-12-21T05:00:00</datetime2>
<int2>1926</int2>
<nvarchar1>i:0#.w|username</nvarchar1>
<nvarchar2>i:0#.w|username</nvarchar2>
<nvarchar3>doc</nvarchar3>
<nvarchar7>BLUES</nvarchar7>
<nvarchar10>K7WP3XQJ2JDF-13-19431</nvarchar10>
<nvarchar11>/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=K7WP3XQJ2JDF-13-19431</nvarchar11>
<nvarchar12>K7WP3XQJ2JDF-13-19431</nvarchar12>
<nvarchar27>SOLD</nvarchar27>
```

Am I looking in the wrong place? Is there some setting causing my data to be stored like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an architectural change in 2013. See: http://joelblogs.co.uk/2013/02/15/sharepoint-2013-content-databases-and-the-alluserdata-table/

EDIT: The article above has been updated/corrected. Thanks Mike D.!

Comment: This design change is mindbogglingly bad. Take all the benefits of using a relational database and throw them out the window by serializing to XML first and storing in a single column.

Comment: Sharepoint isn't actually serializing the data to XML. SQL Server is using sparse columns and returning a column set: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx